# Python - Select an option from a list in Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I am in the process of creating a function that allows the user to interface with a website via Python. Specifically, the user will be provided with a list of options to select, and the selected option will click on the corresponding link. Let's assume this is my code:

```
crop = input('\n\nSelect a crop: Wheat, Wetland rice, Dryland rice, Maize, Barley, Sorghum, Rye, Pearl millet, '
             'Foxtail millet, Oat, Buckwheat, White potato, Sweet potato, Cassava, \n Yam and Cocoyam, Sugarcane, Sugarbeet,'
             ' Phaseolus bean, Chickpea, Cowpea, Dry pea, Gram, Pigeonpea, Soybean, Sunflower, Rapeseed, Groundnut, Oilpalm, '
             'Olive, Jatropha, \n Cabbage, Carrot, Onion, Tomato, Banana, Citrus, Coconut, Cocoa, Cotton, Flax, Coffee, Tea, '
             'Tobacco, Alfalfa, Pasture, Miscanthus, Switchgrass, Reed canary grass')
```

How would I write the next function that allows one to click on the corresponding link based on his or her answer? Which `driver.find_element_by_` code do I use?

I was thinking of using:

```
Select(driver.find_element_by_css_selector(crop).select_by_value(crop)
```

But it doesn't work.

If it helps, this is the code for the wheat link:

```
<input id="buttonSubmit__dim_fieldcrp2=ce_whe&amp;dimType=crp2&amp;fieldmain=main_py_six_qdns&amp;idPS=1e1d6e7d7ec3368cf13a68fc523d1ed4870e8b45&amp;idAS=0&amp;idFS=0" name="fieldcrp2=ce_whe&amp;dimType=crp2&amp;fieldmain=main_py_six_qdns&amp;idPS=1e1d6e7d7ec3368cf13a68fc523d1ed4870e8b45&amp;idAS=0&amp;idFS=0&amp;_passChanged=true&amp;_eventdim" value="Wheat" onclick="return wf_click(this);" type="submit" class="linksubmit linksubmitfalse" style="border: none;">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you can select your `input` element with the `find_element_by_css_selector` method. As it's allowed by css selectors you can access the attributes of your elements, so in your example for an `input` element with `Wheat` as `value` attribute:

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[value=\"Wheat\"]")
elem.click()
```

If you have many `input` elements with that value you can try to be more precise by previously selecting the parent element of the `input` you are targeting or by adding the class name of you element in the css selector:

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input.linksubmit[value=\"Wheat\"]")
elem.click()
```

To use the value entered by the user you can use the [`format`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) method of your string:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input[value="{}"]'.format(crop))
```

Edit: For the record, the `Select(...)` selenium class is used to models an element with the `select` html tag, allowing you afterwards to `select_by_value` one of it's `option` for example.

Comment: But that only works if I wanted to select Wheat. What if I wanted to select another item on the list? For example, Maize?

Comment: I edited my answer to show how to format you string with the value entered by the user.

Comment: Thank you so kindly! It works! I just added `.click()` to the end of the code, like so `driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input[value="{}"]'.format(crop)).click()`